# Is it possible to mock in Django Behave tests?

Tags: python, django, mocking, python-mock, python-behave

I have seen a lot of articles on unit tests with mocking.

I have a simple checkout form which submits card details to a payment gateway. Is it possible to mock the payment gateway response in [Behave tests](https://github.com/django-behave/django-behave)?

```
@then(u'I submitted checkout form')
def submit_checkout_form(context):
    "Mock your response Do not send/post request to payment gateway, but create order"

@then(u'I see my order successfully created')
def inspect_order_page(context):
    "Thank you page: check product & price"
```

I am wondering, is it possible to mock in Behave tests?

Answer (score 3):

It sure is!

If you just need to mock something for the duration of the step, then you can
use `mock.patch`.

```
# features/steps/step_submit_form.py
from mock import patch

@when(u'I submitted checkout form')
def submit_checkout_form(context):
    with patch('payment.gateway.pay', return_value={'success': True}, spec=True):
        form.submit(fake_form_data)
```

If you need to mock something out for every scenario, you can do this in your
`environment.py`, using the lifecycle function:

```
# features/environment.py
from mock import Mock, patch

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    mock_payment_gateway = Mock()
    mock_payment_gateway.pay.return_value = {'success': True}
    patcher = patch('payment.gateway', mock_payment_gateway)
    patcher.start()
    context.payment_patcher = patcher

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.payment_patcher.stop()
```

If you only want to mock it out for particular scenarios, you can create a
special step that sets up the mock, and then tear down in the lifecycle
functions:

```
# features/steps/step_submit_form.py
from behave import given, when, then
from mock import patch, Mock

@given(u'the payment is successful')
def successful_payment_gateway(context):
    mock_payment_gateway = Mock()
    mock_payment_gateway.pay.return_value = {'success': True}
    patcher = patch('payment.gateway', mock_payment_gateway)
    patcher.start()
    context.patchers.append(patcher)

@when(u'I submitted checkout form')
def submit_checkout_form(context):
    form.submit(fake_form_data, payment.gateway)

@then(u'I see my order successfully created')
def inspect_order_page(context):
    check_product()
```

Strip out the patching after each scenario in `environment.py`:

```
# features/environment.py

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.patchers = []

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    for patcher in context.patchers:
        patcher.stop()
```

Comment: you may have to use `import imporlib` and `importlib.reload(<module>)` to reload the mocked module when mocking is on environment.py. It is read after import time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@then(u'I submitted checkout form')
def submit_checkout_form(context):
    with mock.patch('path.module', mock.Mock(return_value=None)):
        **type here**
```